# Visualizar PDF no android

Tags: java, android, pdf

Preciso inserir um pdf no meu aplicativo; como poderia fazer isso ? Existe um pdf view? 
O pdf irá estar dentro do próprio aplicativo na pasta assets.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Só uma dica sobre Java e android, não tem como colocar aplicativos dentro de `./assets` e executa-los, o que você faz é usar um `Intent` pra acessar outro aplicativo instalado no Android ou então você coloca um biblioteca (.java ou .jar) no teu projeto que da a capacidade do teu aplicativo ler PDFs.

Pra visualizar o PDF com o leitor padrão do aparelho você pode usar o código citado nesta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530506/1518921):

```
File file = new File("CAMINHO DO SEU PDF/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Se talvez houver a possibilidade de não haver um aplicativo pra leitura, talvez você tenha quer usar uma biblioteca como [ieee8023/PDFViewer](https://github.com/ieee8023/PDFViewer), neste caso também terá que usar um `Intent`, esta bem atualizado mas carece de uma documentação.

Como alternativa você pode ver este repositório https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview, pra usa-lo faça algo como:

```
pdfView.fromAsset("CAMINHO DO SEU PDF/example.pdf")
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
    .defaultPage(1)
    .showMinimap(false)
    .enableSwipe(true)
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .load();
```

Comment: amigo , mas nesse caso ele migraria para outro aplicativo correto ? eu queria que ele abra em uma espécie de view dentro do próprio app

Comment: Augusto acho que não, o primeiro exemplo apenas chama, faz tempo que não trabalho com Android, mas o segundo exemplo `pdfView.fromAsset` tenho quase certeza que abre dentro do teu aplicativo :)

Comment: ok obrigado, vou dar uma olhada